# Hard Drive locked by Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

After some hardware chances in my PC, Windows (8.1) won loadmafter the 'Repairing tour system' screen. I hace tried to Access the hard drive from other operating systems (Windows and Linux), with little success (it either appears empty or doesn't show up).

I think Windows 8, has blocked access to the drive, since it half-hibernates when it shutsdown.

I know the data is still there, cause Windows is still in the hard drive, but since I can't access externally, how can I recover my data?

Comment: Windows 8 hasn't blocked access, you have experienced a HDD failure, thus preventing you from accessing the drive.

Comment: @Ramhound Then why Windows is able to boot and use hits own files, while I cant?